# Maven multi-module project with many reports: looking for an example

Tags: maven-2, build-automation

Is there an open source project that can serve as a good example on how to use the [maven site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) to generate reports? I would prefer it to

- consist of many modules, possibly hierarchically structured
- use as many plugins as possible (surefire, jxr, pmd, findbugs, javadoc, checkstyle, you name it)
- the reports should be aggregated: if some tests fail you want to have a single page that shows all modules with failing tests, not only a gazillion individual pages to check
- include enterprisey stuff (WAR, EAR etc), but this is not so important.

The idea is to have something where you can gather ideas on how it is done and what is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example see http://www.bartswennenhuis.nl/2013/12/maven-aggregate-reports-for-multi-module-projects/. Findbugs does not support aggregate reports.

Answer (score 5):

I gave up trying to aggregate reports of a complex multi-modules project with the maven-site-plugin. For this, I use [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/), it's much more powerful (with features like evolution of metrics over time, aggregation, neat drill down, etc) and just works. Have a look at [Nemo](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/), the online demo instance and cry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a project, if there is I want to know it as well. In order to find things in maven you have to know what you're looking for(which is not exactly the same with what you want to accomplish).

If its any help I'm building 13 module project with MAVEN, use cobertura maven plugin, surefire, javadoc, etc .. it works as charm, why are you asking this question, you want to determine the capabilities of maven or ?

Answer (score 1):

this is actually a response to your question. please take a look at the Apache Directory project. it contains two big blocks: the directory server and the tooling support (Eclipse based).

you can find the SVN repository of the Apache Directory Studio (this is a complete directory tooling platform  intended to be used with any LDAP server) here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/studio/trunk/

take a look at the POM file ( http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/studio/trunk/pom.xml ) of this multi module project. it consists out of lots of modules, uses most of the plug-ins you're using and it also aggregates some of the reports.this

Comment: For current visitors: The use of <aggregate>, as Apache Directory currently uses is deprecated. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate.html for more details

Comment: The use of `<reportPlugins>` in the site plugin configuration is not the recommended way. Instead use the `<reporting>` section in the pom. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Configuration_formats

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Violations Maven Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-maven-plugin) to aggregate Findbugs (and many other static code analysis) reports.

It needs to run after the analysis. It will parse their report-files and present them in one unified report. It can, optionally, fail the build depending on number of violations found.